# URL Frame redirection CakePHP

Tags: url, web-hosting

I need to redirect CakePHP installation host to my domain.

Location of my Cakephp installation:
myhosting.com/newsite/

Domain:
www.mydomain.com

I'm currently using URL Frame to direct www.mydomain.com to myhosting.com/newsite/.

Problem

When I load www.mydomain.com, I see all links in the site is pointing to the hosting location - example - myhosting.com/newsite/product/1

It should be pointing to www.mydomain.com/product/1

Any simple way to fix this?

Probably very simple to solve it, but I can't bend it. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In short you generally can't. URL Framed "Redirects" are just a hidden frame pointing at your website, your website is browsed within that frame.

Most if not all framed redirects won't pass the path part of the url to the frame source.

You could coerce Cake to produce the URL's you desire but because framed redirects are usually just static HTML there is no intelligence present to strip off the `/product/1` part and then request `http://www.myhosting.com/product/1` into the frame.

Not only that, because you would be requesting the framed redirect page on each click, you would gradually be browsing a frame within a frame within a frame and so on. Meanwhile, and because it's a frame you still won't see the address in the address bar change.

Comment: To add to this, you would need a host that allows you to point your domain at their nameservers, so the domain works properly.